# Highcharts 3D zoom distance

Tags: angular, highcharts, 3d

Is there a way to set the zoom distance in 3d highcharts? I have seen and tried setting the `fitToPlot: true` but I have no control over the distance, and at times it zooms out farther than necessary (http://jsfiddle.net/suprcool01/xvdcqbyk/24/).

Here is an example where have the chart to a size that fits my dataset (http://jsfiddle.net/rhavelka/y00qhw3w/54/) and you can see that at certain angles both the x and y axis' are out of frame, along with a good portion of data points.

I have found part of a solution which is related to the `chart.options3d.depth` and setting that to a smaller number essentially squashes the zaxis, but I don' have a width or height property to set the x and y axis smaller with it.

Comment: You pasted the same jsfiddle link twice. Was that intentional?

Comment: It wasn't. I have updated the second link

Comment: This example clearly illustrates the bug (disappearing lines): http://jsfiddle.net/rhavelka/y00qhw3w/54/ Please report it here:  https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues